# How do I get JQuery Masonry to recognize added items?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

This is the [same question as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526077/how-to-bind-a-dynamic-div-to-jquery-masonry-plugin), but I have a repro of the issue on JSFiddle up [here](http://jsfiddle.net/richarmstrong/vWS2K/4/). So I thought I'd repost.

JQuery Masonry seems to only assess the children of its container once, on first run. After that, it's impossible to get it to look at the DOM again to get it to reassess its children.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the new content to Masonry's [appended](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/methods.html#appended) method:

```
$("#container").append(content).masonry("appended", content);
```

I updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vWS2K/5/).

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I need to tell Masonry that there's been content appended. It can get that from the DOM just by reloading the bricks when called.

Comment: Well, I guess processing only the new elements scales better when you have a huge number of bricks.

Comment: Maybe. Depends on how many bricks. I have over 150 bricks being dynamically stacked with no discernible lag.

Comment: Masonry caches the items selection so that it doesn't have to do so for every reLayout that gets triggered. This happens a lot as people might be resizing the window.  Your solution below would work, selecting items over and over again. I consider this an edge case, whereas most people aren't dynamically adding content. And if they are, then there are the methods like appended that will take care of it for them.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have solved this by adding a line to reload the "bricks" to the `_reLayout` function in the JQuery Masonry code at line 305.

```
_reLayout : function( callback ) {

  // This is my added line. 
  // Items might have been added to the DOM since we laid out last.
    this.reloadItems();

  // reset columns
  var i = this.cols;
  this.colYs = [];
  while (i--) {
    this.colYs.push( this.offset.y );
  }
  // apply layout logic to all bricks
  this.layout( this.$bricks, callback );
},

// ====================== Convenience methods ======================

// goes through all children again and gets bricks in proper order
reloadItems : function() {
  this.$bricks = this._getBricks( this.element.children() );
},


reload : function( callback ) {
  this.reloadItems();
  this._init( callback );
},
```

Anyone see any problem with this?

Comment: Thanks Rich, your reloadItems() edit solved my crazy Firefox issue. My masonry content is constantly and quickly being updated with appended bricks via ajax, as well as having bricks removed. In only Firefox, I was getting some bad positioning after about 3 content updates, where the top positions of the first/top row was off, and would stay incorrectly positioned even when resizing or re-calling the .masonry() function. When tracking the values being passed the _placeBrick function I noticed I was getting "setY" values of -Infinity. Again I'm not sure why, but this eliminated the -Infinity va

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped someone else. Maybe I can see about getting it as an option in the released code.

Answer (score 1):

I made use of the `reload` method:

`.masonry( 'reload' )`

Here's the [masonry doc for reload](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/methods.html#reload):

> "Convenience method for triggering reloadItems then .masonry(). Useful for prepending or inserting items."

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery, this will solve all your problems.

You are including Masonry in your html/php page with something like this:

```
<script src="js/masonry.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#ms-container').masonry({
        columnWidth: '.ms-item',
        itemSelector: '.ms-item'
    });
</script>
```

Instead, leave it like this:

```
<script src="js/masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/masonry-init.js"></script>
```

And create the `js/masonry-init.js` file with the following:

```
$('#ms-container').masonry({
    columnWidth: '.ms-item',
    itemSelector: '.ms-item'
});
var masonryUpdate = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#ms-container').masonry();
    }, 500);
}
$(document).on('click', masonryUpdate);
$(document).ajaxComplete(masonryUpdate);
```

Never worry about it again!