# jQuery Masonry and Ajax-fetching to Append Items Causing Image Overlap

Tags: ajax, append, jquery-masonry, getimagesize

Another image overlap issue here using Masonry and Ajax to append items in Wordpress. The first time more items are appended, the images overlap. However, when the page is reloaded, the images no longer overlap. I realize after doing some research this has to do with calculating the height of the images.

From the help page on the Masonry website, it is suggested to use the **getimagesize** function in order to specify the width and height of the images.

However, this is where I am stuck. Because of my limited knowledge of PHP, I have no idea how to utilize this function or where to place it in my code, so I'm looking for a little direction here. Can anyone help me figure out how to integrate the **getimagesize** function into my code?

Here is the masonry code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $container = $('#loops_wrapper');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.post_box',
        columnWidth: 302

        });
      });
    });
```

This is the ajax fetching code:

```
$('.load_more_cont a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('loading').text('Loading...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).attr('href') + '#loops_wrapper',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(out) {
            result = $(out).find('.post_box');
            nextlink = $(out).find('.load_more_cont a').attr('href');

            $('#loops_wrapper').append(result).masonry('appended', result);
            $('.load_more_cont a').removeClass('loading').text('Load more posts');

            if (nextlink != undefined) {
                $('.load_more_cont a').attr('href', nextlink);
            } else {
                $('.load_more_cont').remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try to implement David DeSandro's timer approach here for appending images...

"As recommended in the primer, the best solution to handle images is to have the size attributes defined in the img tag, especially when using Infinite Scroll. This is the solution employed in the example below.

Of course, this is not a viable option in some CMSs, most notably Tumblr. In this situation, Masonry needs to be called after the newly-appended images are fully loaded. This is done by delaying the Masonry callback."

```
function( newElements ) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $wall.masonry({ appendedContent: $(newElements) });
    }, 1000);
}
```

**EDIT**: If you can't implement the common delay idea for appending items with infinite scroll, you could try reloading after appending new items so instead of

```
$('#loops_wrapper').append(result).masonry('appended', result);
```

do it like that

```
$("#loops_wrapper").append(result).masonry('reload');
```

Comment: Does that make all the images the same width and height? I forgot to mention that while the width is not a problem and will always be the same, it's the height of the images that are going to vary and is what needs to be calculated dynamically.

Comment: No problem, I should have mentioned that the height would vary in size in my original post. I tried the code you posted in my js file, but pardon my lack of know how, I'm guessing I need to change some variables to get it to work with my code? Still stuck.

Comment: Got an online sandbox (undesigned trial site) or jsfiddle so one can see problem live? Easier to tell then where what code should/must go.

Comment: Tried `$("#loops_wrapper").append(result).masonry('reload');` which caused the images to duplicate and overlap even worse.

Comment: I noticed that http://stackoverflow.com/q/7853779/963514 discusses the same and what I answered also. Your issue, which many others have, is simply that Masonry needs the dimensions of elements; hiding and retriggering - or a timeout - make sure that that data is available. Resizing the browser window will correct the layout, because by that time, the dimension data is available. See also https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/50

Comment: I also saw that and implemented **$(window).load()** however still getting the overlap. Thanks for your help anyway. What I am having trouble figuring out is how to use the **getimagesize** function to see if that will fix the issue.

Comment: I could kiss you right now for this piece of code:

$("#loops_wrapper").append(result).masonry('reload');

:) thank you!

Comment: im getting an error msg: `no such method 'reload' for masonry instance`

Comment: I think it is now 'reloadItems', not 'reload'.