# jQuery Masonry images stacked on top

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm using this to call and activate jQuery Masonry.

```
<script>    
  jQuery("#content").load("recent.html", function(){
    $('#masonryContainer').masonry({  
      // options
      itemSelector : '.item',
      columnWidth : 10,
      isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions,
      easing: 'linear' 
    });
  });
</script>
```

The problem is when the page is loaded all the images (they're in div's in recent.html) are stacked on top of each other. I have to first resize the browser window before masonry activates and animates/arranges the images. I'd like it to do this right away coming in.

Comment: Have you specified the height and width of your images in your HTML? That's also a typical reason for Masonry not layouting right away, because it can't reserve the necessary space for loading images and thus can't work out the correct layout.

Comment: I've specified width for the class "item". If I specify a height Masonry will not work properly, as the space between images will then be based on what height I specify and not according to Masonry's arrangement.

Comment: Masonry needs the height and width of an element to work out the layout correctly. So, when your loading your images or contents with Ajax (is that what you load them with?), you might have the same problem others did http://stackoverflow.com/q/12093378/963514 But maybe Liam's answer is right; hard to tell without a jsfiddle or your online sandbox.

Comment: Have you tried triggering layout? $('#masonryContainer').masonry('layout'); Call this once your window loads.

Answer (score 1):

I think your missing a ready:

```
<script>  
  $(window).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#content").load("recent.html", function(){
    $('#masonryContainer').masonry({  
      // options
      itemSelector : '.item',
      columnWidth : 10,
      isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions,
      easing: 'linear' 
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Other JS libraries can cause issues with the layout on page load. For example jQuery Mobile doesn't play well with jQuery Masonry and will produce the above issue. If this is the case remove other JS libraries until you find the culprit.