# jQuery Masonry and AJAX formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, jquery-masonry

When I use AJAX to filter my jQuery Masonry boxes on a page, the formatting doesn't adjust. I tried following the response to this question: [jQuery Masonry and Ajax-fetching to Append Items Causing Image Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093378/jquery-masonry-and-ajax-fetching-to-append-items-causing-image-overlap?rq=1) but it still doesn't work. Anyone have suggestions? My code is below

```
$ -> 
$('#all-content').on 'click', (e) ->
    console.log 'click', this, arguments
    element = $(e.currentTarget)
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax {
        url: element.attr('href')
        complete: (xhr, status) ->
            console.log 'complete', this, arguments
            $('#content').append(e).masonry('reload').html xhr.responseText
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the [masonry.appended](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended) after appending items to the container

```
$('#content').append(elements);
$('#content').masonry( 'appended', elements );
```

**NOTE** : elements is an Array of Elements(not JQuery object)