# dynamic DOM masonry jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating `dom` elements by parsing `tumblr`'s json file.
After the images are loaded, i would like to apply a [jQuery plugin Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html) to tighten up the image grid.
Heres my attempt but it doesnt seem to be responding
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
var container = $('#output');
$.getJSON("http://mydomain.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?", function(data) { 
    $.each(data["posts"], function(i){
        var img = data["posts"][i]["photo-url-400"];
        container.append('<div class="box"><a href="temp.php?var='+i+'"><img src="'+img+'" alt="" /></a></div>');
    });
});


//container.live('imagesLoaded', function(){
container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.box',
        columnWidth : 400
    });
});
```

or this

```
var container = $('#output');
$.getJSON("http://mydomain.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?", function(data) { 
        $.each(data["posts"], function(i){
                var img = data["posts"][i]["photo-url-400"];
                container.append('<div class="box"><a href="temp.php?var='+i+'"><img src="'+img+'" alt="" /></a></div>', function(){
                    container.imagesLoaded( function(){
                        container.masonry({
                                itemSelector: '.box',
                                columnWidth : 400
                        });
                });
        });
});
```

Comment: going to need to see the json format unless you aren't have a problem transversing it?

Comment: the jSon parses fine, it outputs into the DOM.  its just the masonry part thats not responding

Comment: this helped  great deal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526077/how-to-bind-a-dynamic-div-to-jquery-masonry-plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
// Nothing changed here:
var container = $('#output');
$.getJSON("http://mydomain.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?", function(data) { 
    $.each(data["posts"], function(i){
        var img = data["posts"][i]["photo-url-400"];
        container.append('<div class="box"><a href="temp.php?var='+i+'"><img src="'+img+'" alt="" /></a></div>');
    });
});

// Now, do this:
container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    columnWidth : 400
});
var masonryUpdate = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        container.masonry();
    }, 500);
}
$(document).on('click', masonryUpdate);
$(document).ajaxComplete(masonryUpdate);
```

Never worry about it again!

Comment: Please be sure to keep in mind that we expect answers to *specifically* address the question being asked. If there is code in the question, your answer should address that code itself.