# Ajax Loadmore + Shuffle.js, results not laying out

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shuffle, masonry

I'm using the latest shuffle with filtering, search and attempting to load more via ajax.

I'm initiating like so:

```
var Shuffle = window.shuffle;

var bookList = function(element) {
this.element = element;

this.shuffle = new Shuffle(element, {
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
});
```

This works fine and filtering and such works.

I have an ajax load more with a PHP call in there:

```
function getMoreData(lastId) {
$(window).off("scroll");
$.ajax({
url: 'getmore.php?lastId=' + lastId,
type: "get",
beforeSend: function ()
{
$('.ajax-loader').show();
},
success: function (data) {
setTimeout(function() {
$('.ajax-loader').hide();

            var $newItems = $(data);
            $(".grid").append($newItems);
            window.shuffle.add($newItems.get());

           }, 1000);

    }

});
}
```

The items are called but sit behind the first bunch of results and the filtering and search doesn't work for the new items.

Am I missing something? Looking at my inspector I can see the new results aren't having the shuffle classed added: https://share.getcloudapp.com/geuo9KZ0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi , check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895622/10606400) answer might be helpful.

Comment: No that's masonry not shuffle, thanks anyway.

Comment: I solved by using Isotope, Shuffle isn't great it turns out.